# I don't understand why raise NotImplementedError() is necessary here. (python)

Tags: python

I am doing a course in regression and I have to edit a certain jupyter notebook file as an assignment. However, at the end of each cell, they have put 'raise NotImplementedError()'. If I remove it, everything seems to work according to instruction. But if I leave it, naturally, I get an error. I'm not sure why they have done that. For example, this is the column where I have to separate my data:

```
bank_features = None # explanatory features - 16 total
bank_output = None # output feature
# YOUR CODE HERE
raise NotImplementedError()
```

If I separate it without the error line, it works. But the error like breaks it. What should I do, should I just remove it? It's at the end of EVERY cell.

Comment: Obviously you are meant to remove it when implementing your code, along with the `# YOUR CODE HERE` comment

Answer (score 6):

```
raise NotImplementedError()
```

is just there so you're reminded to *implement* the method (an empty stub would just do nothing and there would be bugs because some features aren't implemented)

Of course, when you're done, remove this statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove it, it is a placeholder for you. If you forget to implement a part of the assignment, it will be obvious for you and the examiner to spot.